# TypeScript - Initialization error in WebStorm after update to Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, angular7

I am using WebStorm (version 2018.2.5) for developing my Angular application.
After updating to Angular 7, I always get the following error in the TypeScript window of WebStorm:

```
Error:Initialization error (angular 2 language service). Cannot read property 'CommandTypes' of undefined
```

After research I found this tracked issue from JetBrains and it says it is fixed with version 2018.2.3.[link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34463)

So I shouldn't get this error anymore? But it is still there..
My app still can compile and run commands like `ng serve` so my application runs anyway correctly.

Anyone has an idea how to get rid of this error? Is this error JetBrains WebStorm related?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[WEB-34463](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34463) is fixed in [2018.3 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/), fix is *not* available in 2018.2.5.

As a workaround, try changing Typescript version to *Bundled* in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, or disable Angular language service there

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice this. Disabling angular language service works for now

Comment: Worked for me. Bundled typescript is v3.0.1, while in project I have v3.2.4

Comment: Thank you, sir. You turned my sadness into relief.